# How to remove rows from SQL result if that are same in vice-versa way

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, I am getting 2 rows and as you see here, both rows are same just in vice-versa way.

```
SELECT
    a.SID, a.SID_SCH, a.EXCLUDED_SID, a.EXCLUDED_SID_SCH, 
    c.DESC, d.DESC EXCLUDED_DESC 
FROM
    EXCLUSIONS A
INNER JOIN
    ITEMS B ON a.SID = b.SID AND a.SID_sch = b.SID_sch
INNER JOIN
    code c ON a.SID = c.SID AND a.SID_sch = c.SID_sch
INNER JOIN
    code d ON a.EXCLUDED_SID = d.SID AND a.EXCLUDED_SID_SCH = d.SID_sch
WHERE 
    b.ITEM_ID IN ('D5FAF478-CF43-40E1-BE79-BB90147A3194',
                  '2E79B23E-D264-4901-A065-7E0B7032A5D8')
```

Output

```
072 A   010 A   Create    Create1
010 A   072 A   Create1   Create
```

Please help to get only one record.

Comment: Change `select a.SID, ...` to `select top 1 a.SID, ...` to get just one record, but that's probably not what you are looking for. One of your joins is doubling your rows. Comment out `inner join code c` and `inner join code d` lines and see if you get 1 row. If you do, uncomment `inner join code c` and see if you get 1 row. That'll help you find which inner join creates duplicate rows. Add some sample data to your quest that show the error.

Comment: If your data is always in pair, you can consider to show only one with `WHERE a.SID > a.EXCLUDED_SID`

Comment: @zedfoxus, there is a reason behind why I am doubling it. I would like to get `c.DESC, d.DESC EXCLUDED_DESC`. I can't achieve this unless I join this.

Comment: @Squirrel, No, data is not always in pair.

Comment: Please provide more samples data of all possible scenario and include the expected result

Comment: They are not actually duplicate rows. In the first row, 72 and "A" came from the SID and SID_SCH columns. In the second row, those same values are from the EXCLUDED_SID and EXCLUDED_SID_SCH columns. If this situation is always the case,you could perhaps filter `WHERE a.SID < a.EXCLUDED_SID`. If this is only sometimes the case, you may need to add a more complex condition that in-part checks for `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EXCLUDED WHERE` *values are swapped* `)`

Comment: @TN, this is not always the case. Can you please provide a solution for this one. Thank you

Comment: @testtest what is your desired output? Do you have sample data to share with us?

Comment: @zedfoxus, in thi scenario, the desired output should be only one row. But, again, this is something not always the case. Sometimes, there will be one row only.

Comment: What makes you think they are duplicate rows? If they are SIDs for groups, for example, they'd seem to be disjoint sets on a Venn diagram... "072 but not 010" and "010 but not 072".

Comment: I don't think you will get much more from us unless you provide better sample data covering all possible scenarios along with expected results (as previously requested).